# If some condition happens, how to execute redirect actions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to JavaScript but have worked on HTML from time to time.

I've made a text box with a button "Enter" to enter the answer, the problem is I don't know how to really make the script (since I'm very new to JS). I want to know how to redirect the user to a new page, if
the answer is correct from the text box where they input.

I am also new to this website, so I might not know what to do here to start off with.

Here's the code:

```js
function submit() {
  var bynavn;
  if (bynavn == "Vonsild") {
    location.href = "/lykkelig.htm"
  } else {
    location.href = ""
  }
  document.getElementById('knap').src = enter;
  document.getElementById('tekst').src = bynavn;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>Niveau 5</title>
  <link href="/ZPWSODwhnzO!SJKAzmaPQ/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="hvorervihenne.png" width="1199" height="611" />
    <br> Hvor er vi?: <input type="text" id="tekst">
    <button onclick id="knap">Enter</button>
    <script src="/svar.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

I've tried looking on this website, looking after my issue, but it was in a different coding language and I didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Niveau 5</title>
    <link href="/ZPWSODwhnzO!SJKAzmaPQ/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="hvorervihenne.png" width="1199" height="611"/>
      <br>
      Hvor er vi?: <input type="text" id="tekst">
      <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Enter</button>
      <script src="/svar.js"></script>
    </div>
    <script>
      function checkAnswer() {
        var bynavn = document.getElementById('tekst').value;
        
        if (bynavn.toLowerCase() === "vonsild") {
          window.location.href = "/lykkelig.htm";
        } else {
          window.location.href = ""; // Provide the URL you want to redirect to on incorrect answer
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```